# Load data in sqlite

Tags: python, python-2.x, sqlite

I have written small application for inserting data into sqlite. can you please review.

1. create data from specified path
2. create Table into sqlite database
3. Path format /user/proj/file

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse
from datetime import datetime
import subprocess
import sys
import sqlite3
import scandir
import os

def parse_args(argv):
    """Parsing Argument"""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="This module update data base",
                                     epilog = "update database for each user")
    parser.add_argument('-mng', '-manager', dest='mng', default=['test'], nargs ="*",
                        help="Please provide manager name")
    parser.add_argument('-path', '-p', dest='path', required=True,
                        help="Please provide path from where data needs to load")
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)
    return args



class Singleton(object):
    """
    create Singleton class
    """
    _instances = {}
    def __new__(class_, *args, **kwargs):
        if class_ not in class_._instances:
            class_._instances[class_] = super(Singleton, class_).__new__(class_, *args, **kwargs)
        return class_._instances[class_]

class DB(Singleton):
    """
    Create DataBae, Table and Insert Data into DataBase
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """Invoke parent class and return one instance"""
        super(DB, self).__init__(self)
        self.db_file = "EmpRun"
        self.create_db(self.db_file)

    def create_db(self, db_file):
        """create a database file"""
        try:
            conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        except Error as e:
            print e
        finally:
            conn.close()

    def create_connection(self):
        """
        create a DataBase connection to SQLlite DataBase
        specified by DataBase connection
        Input : DataBase file
        Output : Connection object or None
        """
        try:
            con = sqlite3.connect(self.db_file)
            return con
        except Error as e:
            print (e)
        return None

    def excute_sql(self, conn, sql_query, sql_query_data=""):
        """
        Excute sql query into SQLite DataBase
        Input : connection object
        Ouput : Sql query executation
        Return : Pass or Fail
        """
        try:
            c = conn.cursor()
            if sql_query_data:
                c.execute(sql_query, sql_query_data)
            else:
                c.execute(sql_query)

        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            print (e)
            return 1
        return 0

    def create_table(self, conn):
        """
        create a table from the create_table_sql statement
        Input : connection object
        Output : create table statement
        return :
        """
        emp_run_detail = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EMPRUN(
                        emp_name varname(50),
                        proj varname(100),
                        file_data text NOT NULL,
                        time varchar(50) NOT NULL
                        );"""
        if not self.excute_sql(conn, emp_run_detail):
            print "Query : %s Excuted successfully" %(emp_run_detail)
        else:
            print "Query : %s Excuted Failed" %(emp_run_detail)
            sys.exit(0)

    def extract_info_user(self, index, data, f_name_path):
        """
        Input : Index, data
        Ouput : Tuple with user, proj, file_info
        """
        user = data[index+1]
        proj = data[-2]
        f_name = []
        with open(f_name_path, "r") as fp:
            f_name = fp.read()
        ttime = str(datetime.now())  
        if user == proj:
            proj = user + "_" + os.path.basename(f_name_path) + "_" + ttime
        return(user, proj, f_name, ttime)

    def extract_info(self, path):
        """
        Input : path where all information is stored
        Ouput : return information as list
        """
        file_info = []
        for root, dirs, files in scandir.walk(path):
            for fi in files:
                file_info.append(os.path.join(root, fi))
        user_info = []
        lpath = os.path.basename(path)
        for info in file_info:
            f_data = info.split("/")
            f_index = f_data.index(lpath)
            user_info.append(self.extract_info_user(f_index, f_data, info))
        return user_info

    def insert_data(self, path, conn):
        """
        Insert Data into Table
        Input : Path, where data is located
              : Data Inserted into table
        output : query successful
        """
        emp_run_data =  self.extract_info(path)
        query = """INSERT INTO EMPRUN(emp_name, proj, file_data, time) VALUES(
              ?, ?, ?, ?)"""
        for emp_run in emp_run_data:
            if not self.excute_sql(conn, query, emp_run):
                print "Query : %s Excuted successfully" %(list(emp_run))
            else:
                print "Query : %s Excuted Failed" %(list(emp_run))
                sys.exit(0)

def main(args):

    database = DB()
    dcon = database.create_connection()
    database.create_table(dcon)
    database.insert_data(args.path, dcon)
    dcon.commit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ARGV = parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
    sys.exit(main(ARGV))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some of the things I would work on:

- [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) code style violations, to name a few:

  - group and sort imports correctly
  - two blank lines after the import statements
  - docstrings should start with a capital letter, end with a dot
  - two blank lines between the class and function definitions
- remove unused `subprocess` import
- fix typos: `excute_sql` -> `execute_sql`, `Ouput` -> `Output`, `executation` -> `execution`, `Excute` -> `Execute`, `SQLlite` -> `SQLite`, `DataBae` -> `DataBase`
- use `print()` as a function for Python 3.x compatibility
- `f_name = []` is unused, remove it
- I also see `Error` is not defined here: `except Error as e:` - did you mean `except sqlite3.Error as e:`?
- there is no need to return `None` at the end of the `create_connection()` function

---

I would also re-format the SQL queries for better readability, for instance, replacing:

```
query = """INSERT INTO EMPRUN(emp_name, proj, file_data, time) VALUES(
      ?, ?, ?, ?)"""
```

with:

```
query = """
    INSERT INTO 
        EMPRUN 
        (emp_name, proj, file_data, time) 
    VALUES
        (?, ?, ?, ?)"""
```

---

The `try/finally` block inside `create_db` method is not going to work properly - if `sqlite3.connect()` fails, `conn` variable would not be defined - hence, `conn.close()` in `finally` will fail with a `NameError`.

---

It would also be a good idea to run a static code analysis tool like `pylint` or `flake8` against the code - it would catch most of the code style and PEP8 guide violations.